# Complex integration involving branch cut

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

What's the difference between integrating:

$$\int_{-i}^i {z^{\frac{1}{3}}} \: dz$$ on the principal branch, and on the branch $\pi<\arg(z)<3\pi$?

Comment: My immediate guess is that the end result is multiplied by $e^{2\pi i/3}$.

Comment: @Arthur May I ask how you know that?

Comment: I don't know, I _guess_. But the value of $z^{1/3}$ on the new branch cut is $e^{2\pi i/3}$ times the value of $z^{1/3}$ on the standard cut. If all is good in this world, then this is a constant factor you can just move outside the integral.